# Obtaining values from an XML file for database insert

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an xml file of following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tryton>
<data skiptest="1" noupdate="1">
<record model="test.pathology.category" id="icdcat1">
<field name="name">I Certain infectious and parasitic diseases</field>
</record>

<record model="test.pathology.category" id="icdcat2">
<field name="name">II Neoplasms</field>
</record>
```

and further down:

```
<record model="test.pathology.category" id="icdcat1-1">
<field name="name">(A00-A09) Intestinal infectious diseases</field>
<field name="parent" ref="icdcat1"></field>
</record>

<record model="test.pathology.category" id="icdcat2-6">
<field name="name">(C45-C49) Malignant neoplasms of mesothelial and soft tissue</field>
<field name="parent" ref="icdcat2"></field>
</record>
</data>
</tryton>
```

I tried the following:

```
<?php
if(file_exists('xml/myfile.xml'))
   {
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml/myfile.xml', 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
}
print_r($xml);
?>
```

print_r gives the following values:

```
 SimpleXMLElement Object ( [data] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [skiptest] => 1 [noupdate] => 1 ) [comment] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [record] => Array ( 
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [model] => test.pathology.category [id] => icdcat1 ) [field] => I Certain infectious and parasitic diseases ) 
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [model] => test.pathology.category [id] => icdcat2 ) [field] => II Neoplasms )
```

and further down:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [model] => test.pathology.category [id] => icdcat1-1 ) [field] => Array ( 
[0] => (A00-A09) Intestinal infectious diseases 
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => parent [ref] => icdcat1 ) ) ) ) [23] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [model] => test.pathology.category [id] => icdcat1-2 )
```

I tried something like:

```
foreach($xml->data->record[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

and i am getting :

```
model="test.pathology.category" id="icdcat1"
```

**For insert in database, i need the following:**
**From part 1:**

```
[id] => icdcat1 ) 
[field] => I Certain infectious and parasitic diseases
```

**and in second part:**

```
id="icdcat1-1"
name = (A00-A09) Intestinal infectious diseases
ref="icdcat1" 2 etc...
```

Confused as i am a newbie programmer. Help requested.

Comment: What's the point in encoding/decoding data?

Comment: @ u_mulder Sorry, was testing. ..Post updated.

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: @Philipp Maurer Sorry, It was at the top. I have updated the post and it is at the end of the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply iterate over the record elements...

```
foreach($xml->data->record as $record) {
    echo (string)$record['id']."/".(string)$record->field[0].PHP_EOL;
    if ( count($record->field) > 1 )    {
        echo $record->field[1]['ref'].PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The attribute (id) is accessed using `[]` and the value of the field element uses `->`.

The if part checks if there is a second field value and extracts the ref element from it.

With the sample file, this outputs...

```
icdcat1/I Certain infectious and parasitic diseases
icdcat2/II Neoplasms
icdcat1-1/(A00-A09) Intestinal infectious diseases
icdcat1
icdcat2-6/(C45-C49) Malignant neoplasms of mesothelial and soft tissue
icdcat2
```

Comment: Thank You so much. I will try to adapt the code to my needs.

Comment: One thing to check is that when using these values in fields - cast them to a string (the echo if `$record['id']` for example).  Otherwise they will be SimpleXMLElement objects and functions don't always do this type casting for you (`echo` does)

Answer (score 0):

Pls Try This

```
if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file('syntest.xml')){
trigger_error('Error reading XML file',E_USER_ERROR);
}



foreach ($xml as $syn) {
$w1 = $syn->w1;  
$w2 = $syn->w2;     
}
```

Comment: No value. I tried:
foreach ($xml as $syn) 
    {
        $w1 = $syn->w1;  
        $w2 = $syn->w2; 
        echo  $w1;
        echo  $w2;
 }

Comment: simplexml_load_file('syntest.xml')

Comment: Please try to add and explain what your code does and how it solves the problem. And format it properly.

Comment: @remiz_muhammed Sorry, your code does nothing. The xml file is getting properly read and i am getting the print_r values.

Comment: pls var_dump the result

Comment: eg: var_dump($xml);

Comment: @remiz_muhammed object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) { ["data"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (3) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["skiptest"]=> string(1) "1" ["noupdate"]=> string(1) "1" } ["comment"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (0) { } ["record"]=> array(284) 
{ [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) 
{ ["model"]=> string(28) "test.pathology.category" ["id"]=> string(7) "icdcat1" } ["field"]=> string(43) "I Certain infectious and parasitic diseases" }.....

Comment: $xml->data->record as $record     try different methods of extracting data from object result